# How to make select block on a file descriptor

Tags: c, linux

I have a process with two threads. One thread, thread A, will set up timerfd timers and the other thread, thread B, will perform 'select' on those timers. Once a timer expires thread B will indicate this to thread A.

To add timers, thread A will create a new timer and then it will wake up thread B to include this timer in its call to select. I'm trying to wake up thread B by using a file descriptor just for that purpose. Thread B would then call select on that FD and all the FD's returned by calls to timerfd.

The problem is that I cannot manage to create a FD that I can control in a way so that it will cause select to block, or return, when I want.

I have tried to use shm_open with calls to fcntl, and i have tried to just use open on a file, but none of them will cause select to block. All my attempts causes select to return immediately. Is there any way to create a FD that will cause select to block until I update that FD somehow?

Try 1 - Create a FD with shm_open and use fcntl to set read lock:

Create the FD from thread A.

```
if((wakeUpFd = shm_open("/wakeup", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0)) == -1)
   printf("Failed to open /wakeup, Errno = %d\n", errno);
else
{
   fcntl(wakeUpFd, F_SETLK, F_RDLCK);
}
```

Add timer from thread A.

```
#create a timer and add it to a list
/* wake up timer thread */
fcntl(wakeUpFd, F_SETLK, ~F_RDLCK);
```

Wake up thread B

```
#when select returns
if(FD_ISSET(wakeUpFd, &timerSet))
{
   fcntl(wakeUpFd, F_SETLK, F_RDLCK);
}
#check all other timer FD's
```

Try 2 - Use shm_open and read/write data to it:

Create the FD from thread A.

```
if((wakeUpFd = shm_open("/wakeup", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0)) == -1)
   printf("Failed to open /wakeup, Errno = %d\n", errno);
else
{
   if(ftruncate(wakeUpFd, 2) == -1)
   {
      printf("Failed with ftruncate, Errno = %d\n", errno);
   }
}
```

Add timer from thread A.

```
#create a timer and add it to a list
/* wake up timer thread */
if(write(wakeUpFd, wakeUpStr, 1) != 1)
   printf("Failed to write to wakeUpFd\n");
```

Wake up thread B

```
#when select returns
if(FD_ISSET(wakeUpFd, &timerSet))
{
   read(wakeUpFd, wakeUpBuf, 10);
}
#check all other timer FD's
```

Try 3 - Pretty much the same as Try 2 but use open instead of shm_open.

Try 4 - Same as Try 1 but with fcntl(wakeUpFd, F_SETFL, ~O_NONBLOCK) instead of the fcntl(wakeUpFd, F_SETLK, ~F_RDLCK)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  You've done a nice job here explaining what you've tried, and clearly trying a fair amount before asking.  Well done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [`select()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) specification, especially the bit where it says:

> File descriptors associated with regular files shall always select true for ready to read, ready to write, and error conditions.

You can't make `select()` block on file descriptors for regular files.  You'd have to have a pipe, or socket, or something along those lines, as the file you `select()` on.

Answer (score 1):

Use an Unix domain socket pair, for example [`socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0, commsd)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socketpair.2.html) for the communications. When thread A creates a new timerfd, it simply writes the new descriptor, an `int`, to the communications socket `commsd[0]`.

When thread B notices that the communications socket `commsd[1]` is readable, it reads one or more `int`s from it. Each `int` is obviously a new timerd descriptor, so thread B has to add each one to the set it `select()`s on.

In thread B, I recommend using nonblocking reads, [`bytes = recv(commfd, ptr, len, MSG_DONTWAIT)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) in a loop to read from the communications socket:

```
    char     buffer[8 * sizeof(int)];
    size_t   head = 0, tail = 0;
    ssize_t  bytes;
    int      new_timerfd;

    while (1) {

        if (head >= tail)
            head = tail = 0;
        else
        if (head > 0) {
            memmove(buffer, buffer + head, tail - head);
            tail -= head;
            head = 0;
        }

        if (tail < sizeof buffer) {
            bytes = recv(commsd[1], buffer + head, sizeof buffer - tail, MSG_DONTWAIT);
            if (bytes > (ssize_t)0)
                head += bytes;
        }

        if (head >= tail)
            break;

        while (head + sizeof (int) <= tail) {
            /* Unaligned version of new_timerfd = *(int *)(buffer + head); */
            memmove(&new_timerfd, buffer + head, sizeof new_timerfd);
            head += sizeof (int);

            /*
             * Add new_timerfd to select()ed set
            */
        }
    }
```

The above loop does do an extra nonblocking `recv()` call to detect it has read all that is immediately pending, but this way it is extremely robust. It does not even assume you can always read a full `int`. (Since `_POSIX_PIPE_BUF` is always a multiple of `sizeof int`, you could assume you always read full `int`.)

The above loop does a nonblocking receive from the socket for as long as there is data available, and the loop body will extract the descriptors to `new_timerfd` one by one. I omitted the code that adds it to the `select()`ed sets.

Finally, this approach works in the general case, too, when you transfer a larger structure to a thread that does `select()` in a loop. Just make sure the buffer is large enough for at least two structures, and you're set; the `memmove()`s handle any buffer packing and structure alignment issues you might otherwise have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nominal Animal, it is very thorough. In my case I handle the communication through the memory though. The FD is just for waking the timer handler up. A pipe was the fastest way for me to do that.